# Need to copy image from res folder to gallery/folder

Tags: android, image, copy, gallery, drawable

Ok, so i have Gallery Application, with lots of images in it(res/drawable).

On selection you can Set as Wallpaper button and you will have it.

Now i want to save with button SAVE TO PHONE or SD card this image selected. How can i manage that. Copying from res of application folder to Phone or SD card. Dont want to take it from ImageView but just copy the original from res to Phone.

Comment: You can find an answer which should do for you here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939170/resources-openrawresource-issue-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
  myDir.mkdirs();
  Random generator = new Random();
  int n = 10000;
  n = generator.nextInt(n);
  String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
  File file = new File (myDir, fname);
  if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
  try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and add in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps :-

- Create `Bitmap` using  [BitmapFactory.decodeResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29)
- Write the contents of Bitmap to an `OutputStream` using [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)
- Save the file to anywhere you want.

Code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
file = new File(path, "image.jpg");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources(), R.drawable.xyz);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: this one is working. Now  how can i set file name and what folder to save, cuz now i am getting image to /DCIM/Camera/somerandomnumber.jpg

Comment: You are getting random number as name because there might be an image already present with `image.jpg` name. So, use some unique name(like the present date time).
check the mehtod `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html), the third parameter is the name of the image.