# Access to resource folder route

Tags: android, resources

I'm developing a test class that have to check if there are all the resources. It's a specification mandatory that i access to the resources by file name (png's).

I know there's the possibility of loading as a resource, but I cannot load resources. I'm developing a test app. How I could access the file `file.png` in res/drawable named ?

```
new FileOutputStream("/res/drawable/xxx.png");
```

Comment: Please explain "what" your are trying to do before trying to find the "how".

Comment: Did you search to solve your problem?

Comment: I have edited the question to become it clearer. Ia have not found the solution

Comment: Yes, i have searched but im  didn't find. Sorry, i'm not an android expert developer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to get access to raw resources that i put in res folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to read [**Resources Overview**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html) from Android docs,but if your problem is only about accessing resources,read [**Accessing Resources**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).So you can do what you want.

Summery,there is some ways to access resources that depends on situations,for example when you know name of resource or you know it's ID.And also it depends that where you want to access resources.

In your case I guess that you want to access a `drawable` in your code,if it is true,you can do like this:

> R.drawable.xxx

For example if name of your .png file is *myimage* and you have to set it in *ImageView* with name *im* do this:

```
ImageView im = ...;
im.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

**Edit**:

If you have to get an `InputStream` form a file in resources,you should consider creating a `raw` folder inside res directory and put your file in it and then call getResources().openRawResource(resourceName) from your Activity or widget.For example :

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```

Here your file that is in raw folder is for example `test.png`.

You can see more details here:

[Using files as raw resources in Android](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/27/using-files-as-raw-resources-in-android/)

[Android: Loading files from the Assets and Raw folders](http://www.41post.com/3985/programming/android-loading-files-from-the-assets-and-raw-folders)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945879/1043882)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856501/1043882)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082182/1043882)

***Finally if you want to create an output file from your resource,get an InputStream from it and write it's content to an OutputStream,you can see a good example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/File/Createanoutputfilefromrawresources.htm).***

Comment: Thanks. I knwe how to access to resources as resources. But i need to access via path and file name. I have to do it in this way, no other.

Comment: @Joterito what do you want to do?

Comment: First of all, sorry for my english, it's very poor. What i wan't to do is access to a png i have in drawable folder but not as resource. I want to access by the file name. new FileOutputStream("/res/drawable/xxx.png"); What i don't know is the path of the file in resources folder. /res/drawable/? (getFilesDir()+"/res/drawable? Sorry if i don't explain very well and thanks