# Android: ArrayList of resource identifiers returning int value

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-resources

I am trying to store resource identifiers for some mp3 files in an array.
Here is the code.

```
    private HashMap<String,List<Integer>> listHashMapnum;
    private List<String> listhead;



    listhead.add("Forty");
    listhead.add("Fifty");
    ArrayList<Integer> fortysound = new ArrayList<>();
    fortysound.add(R.raw.forty);
    ArrayList<Integer> fiftysound = new ArrayList<>();
    fiftysound.add(R.raw.fifty);
```

Then I store the array list in a hashmap

```
 listHashMapnum.put(listhead.get(0),fortysound);
 listHashMapnum.put(listhead.get(1),fiftysound);
```

Then I use a function to get the value in the hashmap

```
 public Integer getChild2(int i, int i1) {
    return listHashMapnum.get(listheader.get(i)).get(i1);
}
```

I get the value from the function like this

```
 Integer childsound = (Integer) getChild2(i, i1);
```

I then use the childsound variable to initialize the mediaplayer

```
    Button bt;

    bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.speaker);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, childsound);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            mp.start();
        }

    });
```

But the function returns a int value like "213736282" I found this out while trying to debug.
 But I don't understand why it does that and what I can do to get my resource identifier from the function.
 Any help is totally appreciated.
 Thank you.

Edit:
The error was actually in another part of the code so the code above is correct. Thank you

Comment: please see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the declarations of all the variables used here, so we know their types.

Comment: You did get it. What makes you think there's a problem?

Comment: @Oleg because the app keeps crashing at that point and when I try debugging I found out the childsound variable is having a value of int that looks this way "213585932"

Comment: What are you doing with `childsound`? the problem is probably there.

Comment: I am using it to setup the mediaplayer here is the code

Comment: Button bt;

        bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, childsound);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                mp.start();
            }

        });

Comment: And does it work when you pass `R.raw.forty` to it? What does it equal to?

Comment: @Oleg thanks very much. I just did that and the app still crashed then I started checking other parts of the code and found the error was an iteration I made while debugging but didn't change it back which was an array that I added two items instead of one. Thanks very much buddy saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Android resource identifier are integer values which is generated and stored in R.java.

You can [openRawResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)) method and read the resources

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945879/1066839) for reading mp3 from raw resources